# How to traverse DataTable table rows to check status of each checkbox element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have turned my HTML table into a Datatable using the Datatables API.  I have a checkbox on each row and if I check them and navigate to another page and then come back to it, it looks like the Datatable remembers the DOM state of each row elements, including each checkbox.

How would I be able to traverse across each table row to check the status of each row's checkbox using the DataTable object?

I would normally be using jQuery for example to do the check if it was a normal table for each row by doing:

`$(rowElement).find(':checkbox').is(':checked')`

But it looks like myDataTable.data() does not store the element as DOM elements, so I'm not sure how to do the check.

Comment: When using the DataTables API, you can access the data associated with each row, but the DataTables API does not store the actual DOM elements in the data() method. Instead, it stores the underlying data used to populate the table.

To check the status of each row's checkbox in DataTables, you can use the rows().nodes() method to get the array of nodes (DOM elements) for the rows currently in the table. Then, for each row, you can find the checkbox within that row.

Comment: I tested that and I was able to check the status of the checkbox for each row element.  Thank you.